# Keep doctrine entity up-to-date with external SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a Symfony project which connects to several databases. However, I only have ALTER access on one of them.

At the moment to keep my doctrine entities in-sync with the database I have to do a `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` then do the opposite to my entity.

e.g. if `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` gives me
ALTER tableName DROP columnName 
I go to the TableName entity and add a columnName property.

`doctrine:schema:import` only seems to work the first time. even after deleting all the .xml file

Is there anything else that I can do/use to keep in-sync that is less manual.

Comment: what do you mean with *then do the opposite to my entity* what is the command exactly? And is there any way to reach an organizational change to the situation, since it is not optimal? or have a more solid DB design?

Comment: @Confidence I only have Read access to the database just to retrieve data from it and that not likely to change. what I mean by _do the opposite to my entity_ is. If they need to add a column say columnNew. My entity doesn't have that column yet and the only way of finding out if the database is out of sync is to do a `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` which will generate the call `ALTER tableName DROP columnA`. then I know that I need to add columnA to my entity.

Comment: It looks like Doctrine Migrations might be what you need to go through these changes https://github.com/doctrine/migrations and the bundle for that http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Comment: Do you mean generate entities from your database?

Comment: Yes @IsraelRodriguezSanchez the entities need to be gerated by the database.

Comment: @Confidence Doctrine migrations wont work for me because it still updates the database to be the same as the <entity not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this doctrine tool to make entities from your database with reverse engineering:

First, you need to do XML metadata files with this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
```

Then, use this to make entities from the XML files:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Comment: This is the closest that I can get to automating it. Although some properties still need to be entered manually. e.g. the default values of the column.